# What is the purpose of the `logMessage` parameter in a fetch command?

Tags: git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

One of the parameters of the Fetch command is the `logMessage`.  Taking an example from [the wiki](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/git-fetch), it passes in an empty string.

```
string logMessage = "";
using (var repo = new Repository("path/to/your/repo"))
{
    var remote = repo.Network.Remotes["origin"];
    var refSpecs = remote.FetchRefSpecs.Select(x => x.Specification);
    Commands.Fetch(repo, remote.Name, refSpecs, null, logMessage);
    //                                                ^^^^^^^^^^---- this
}
Console.WriteLine(logMessage);
```

What exactly is this for anyway?

As far as I know in git, you don't need to provide a message when fetching from a remote. The parameter descriptions says:

> Log message for any ref updates.

But I'm not sure what that means in this context.

Comment: In command-line Git, run `git reflog` and `git reflog origin/master` and you may be enlightened. But I have to guess since this command-line Git is not libgit2sharp.

Comment: Oh nice! So it sets the message that appears in the reflog? Didn't know we could do that (that's awesome). There have been times I wished the reflog showed better messages. I think you have it pretty much spot on, worthy of an answer. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqCoc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `logMessage` parameter controls the message that is used in the reflog. So if any commits are fetched, the entry for the affected branch will use that message.